# Why am I getting RecursionError for QuickSort Algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a homework question on creating a quick sort algorithm using a helper function called partition and using recursion.  My code is raising a RecursionError, but I cannot seem to figure out why.

I have tried re-ordering the code, but nothing seems to be working.

```py
def partition(L, p):

    newL = L.copy() # New list of the same size.
    i = 0 # Index for inserting small values.
    j = len(newL)-1 # Index for inserting large values.
    # Iterate through the elements in the old list.
    for ind in range(len(L)):
    # Skip the pivot.
        if ind != p:
            if L[ind] <= L[p]:
                newL[i] = L[ind] # If < pivot, place at i.
                i += 1 # Increment to next open space.
            else:
                newL[j] = L[ind] # If >= pivot, place at j.
                j -= 1 # Decrement to next open space.
    # Now i==j and this is the only open space.
    newL[i] = L[p] # Place the pivot in its spot.
    return (newL, i)


def QuickSort(L):
    if len(L)==0 or len(L)==1:
        return L
    else:
        pivot=L[0]
        newL=partition(L,pivot)[0]
        newPivot=partition(L,pivot)[1]
        L2=newL[newPivot:]
        L1=newL[:newPivot]
        L2=QuickSort(L2)
        L1=QuickSort(L1)
        L=merge(L1,L2)

    return L

if __name__ == '__main__':
    L=[1,0,2]
    print(QuickSort(L))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ellavanengen/eclipse-workspace/hw1/src/hw7.py", line 108, in <module>
    print(QuickSort(L))
  File "/Users/ellavanengen/eclipse-workspace/hw1/src/hw7.py", line 97, in QuickSort
    L2=QuickSort(L2)
  File "/Users/ellavanengen/eclipse-workspace/hw1/src/hw7.py", line 97, in QuickSort
    L2=QuickSort(L2)
  File "/Users/ellavanengen/eclipse-workspace/hw1/src/hw7.py", line 97, in QuickSort
    L2=QuickSort(L2)
  [Previous line repeated 988 more times]
  File "/Users/ellavanengen/eclipse-workspace/hw1/src/hw7.py", line 93, in QuickSort
    newL=partition(L,pivot)[0]
  File "/Users/ellavanengen/eclipse-workspace/hw1/src/hw7.py", line 72, in partition
    for ind in range(len(L)):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: My reading of the QuickSort algorithm is that this `newL[i] = L[ind] # If < pivot, place at i.` should be a full *swap* of the two elements, not just a one way *assignment*.

Comment: You should not completely change your question after you have received answers. If you have a follow-up question, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that prevents `QuickSort()` from exiting the recursion is here:

```py
        pivot=L[0]
        newL=partition(L,pivot)[0]
        newPivot=partition(L,pivot)[1]
        L2=newL[newPivot:]
        L1=newL[:newPivot]
```

Firstly, `pivot` must be initialized with a *position* in the list, not with a *value* from the list. Correcting:

```py
        pivot=0
```

Secondly, don`t forget that the list *enumeration* begins with 0 whereas list *slicing* yields an empty list on `list[:0]` and an unchanged list on `list[0:]`. To slice the list up to the element #`n`, `n ≥ 0`, add 1 to `n`: `beginning = list[:n+1]`. List tails are treated analogously.

So as you can see, the very first recursive call always receives the full list.

Correcting:

```py
        L2=newL[newPivot+1:]
        L1=newL[:newPivot+1]
```

Those two are the major issues. Two somewhat lesser shortcomings are as follows.

Firstly, Python functions that return a tuple are able to assign several variables at once:

```py
        (newL, newPivot) = partition(L,pivot)
```

Secondly, the result of `heapq::merge()` is an iterator, not a list. And furthermore, using it will doubtlessly be considered cheating, for it sorts the resulting list anyway. Write your own `merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the [QuickSort algorithm in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is that you should be able to sort the array *in place* and not do things like `newL = L.copy()`.  And the `merge()` operation you're doing should be a simpler concatenation as the two arrays are already sorted, one of all lower values than the other.  Following the basic *in place* algorithm, I come up with something like:

```
def partition(array, low, high):

    pivot = array[high]

    index = low

    for j in range(low, high):
        if array[j] < pivot:
            array[index], array[j] = array[j], array[index]
            index += 1

    array[index], array[high] = array[high], array[index]

    return index

def quicksort_recursive(array, low, high):
    if low < high:
        index = partition(array, low, high)

        quicksort_recursive(array, low, index - 1)
        quicksort_recursive(array, index + 1, high)

def quicksort(array):

    if len(array) > 1:

        quicksort_recursive(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

    return array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = [13, 5, 31, 63, 39, 61, 14, 19, 37, 93, 88, 55]
    print(quicksort(array))
```

But, if we're willing to waste time and space copying array fragments, and be more Pythonic, we can simplify this significantly to:

```
def partition(array):

    pivot = array[0]

    low = []
    high = []

    for number in array[1:]:
        (low if number < pivot else high).append(number)

    return low, pivot, high

def quicksort(array):

    if len(array) > 1:

        low, middle, high = partition(array)

        return [*quicksort(low), middle, *quicksort(high)]

    return array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = [13, 5, 31, 63, 39, 61, 14, 19, 37, 93, 88, 55]
    print(quicksort(array))
```